# Need help understanding MySQL PACK_KEYS

Tags: mysql, compression, key, bigint

I am using a BIGINT to hold an id number that will increment from 1.  In one table this will be the Primary Key and will, of course, be unique; in other tables it will be a foreign key.  I'm trying to figure out whether this key will be "packed" if I set PACK_KEYS, since there will be a lot of leading zeroes.

I'm having difficulty understanding the MySQL doc for the PACK_KEYS table option in [table creation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-table.html).  Here is the relevant quote from the doc:

> When packing binary number keys, MySQL uses prefix compression:
>
> - Every key needs one extra byte to indicate how many bytes of the
>     previous key are the same for the next key.
> - The pointer to the row is stored in high-byte-first order directly
>     after the key, to improve compression.
>
> This means that if you have ***many equal keys on two consecutive rows,
>   all following “same” keys usually only take two bytes (including the
>   pointer to the row)***. Compare this to the ordinary case where the
>   following keys takes storage_size_for_key + pointer_size (where the
>   pointer size is usually 4). Conversely, you get a significant benefit
>   from prefix compression only if you have many numbers that are the
>   same. If all keys are totally different, you use one byte more per
>   key, if the key is not a key that can have NULL values. (In this case,
>   the packed key length is stored in the same byte that is used to mark
>   if a key is NULL.)

They've lost me with "***many equal keys on two consecutive rows,
all following “same” keys usually only take two bytes (including the
pointer to the row)***".  Can someone interpret the above doc for me, in light of what I'm trying to accomplish?  E.g., for a primary key there won't be ANY "equal keys" - on two consecutive rows, on three consecutive rows, on 100 non-consecutive rows... or whatever they're driving at.

Thanks!

Comment: Chances are you do not need PACK_KEYS. I see you are using BIGINT for your PK. How many rows are you looking at having in this table eventually?? What kind of data are you storing? How do you intend to retrieve/report on it and how often?? These are things I would consider first before using this feature.

Comment: There's a Name table, and an Address table: mailing info, plus a few date fields and dollar amt fields.  We'll be starting off with 800 million rows in the name table and don't want to be taken by surprise if we exceed 2B or 4B over time.  Access will be massive (millions) via batch jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are you do not need PACK_KEYS. I see you are using BIGINT for your PK. How many rows are you looking at having in this table eventually?? What kind of data are you storing? How do you intend to retrieve/report on it and how often?? These are things I would consider first before using this feature.

If I read that documentation correctly, it's basically stating that if you have two consecutive records with long PKs say:

PK-x: 1002350025789001
PK-y: 1002350025789002

With PACK_KEYS, PK-y now becomes something like "[pointer to PK-x]2"

It's basically a way of saying PK-2 is the same as PK-1 except for the last number which is 2... without having to rewrite/store the same refix/preceding numbers.

The gains from this are most likely only realized when you are dealing with very long PKs and will mostly be gains in storage/memory, however I would imagine there's a cost to overall performance which may or may not be noticeable depending on how much access load that table gets.

May not be worth it... I've never used this feature, and I've built some pretty heavy apps on MySQL.

hope this helps.

Good Luck

Comment: I figured I'd be trading 16 bytes per key (8 bytes for BIGINT + 8 bytes for the pointer) for something like 2 bytes per key ("two bytes  including the pointer to the row"), which would be a huge space saving. We hope we can use memory to cache the keys, assuming they'd stay packed once cached.

Comment: Okay, so I read your other comment. Thanks. So it seems like those tables are tracking some type of receipt/invoice/billing transaction data. At 800 million rows PACK_KEYS might yield enough benefits to outweigh the costs. There are a number of things you can do to streamline your data for rapid access especially if you want those batch jobs to complete on time for the next business day. Before getting into memory cache there are quite a few things I would do. MySQL is pretty fast if used properly.

Comment: You may have to consider further normalization and will need an archival process to keep table size down and speed up (based on business requirements of course). Then there's the whole jobs architecture. Reporting jobs should run on a replica database, streamlined for lookups. We can go on all day about this. Sounds like a fun project. Good Luck!

Comment: Fortunately, I'll have 384GB of memory, and 2TB of SSD to throw at it.  Thanks for your help.  It's too soon to run any proof of concept on it, but the hardware should be here by the end of the year.  Yes, fun!

Comment: Network and Disk I/O are gonna be critical going into production, but it sounds like the hardware won't be a problem through development and possibly into production. Feel free to bounce any questions, thoughts and ideas off me as you move forward. Email's on my profile. Cheers!